# Clustering Based-On Multi-Word Similarity

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, word-embedding

I am trying to implement clustering for bank transaction data. The dataset contains columns about `Vendor` and `MCC` which are `string`. There are too much distinct values in those columns, I want to make a clustering depending on some metrics such as `cosine similarity` for `Vendor or MCC`. ( For example `'Hotel A'` and `'Hotel B'` can be in the same cluster. ) I think `Levenshtein distance` is not sufficient for this.

I think about finding a corpus for MCC and create a model for find similarity between the words. Is this method good for this problem? If not, how can I handle with those columns? If yes, is there a corpus for this?

Data source: https://data.world/oklahoma/purchase-card-fiscal-year

Comment: By MCC you mean a merchant category code? Is that a number field?

Comment: Yes,it is merchant category code. No, it is not number, it is a string field such as _PET SHOPS,PET FOOD AND SUPPLIES_

Comment: What is the approx number of unique MCCs and vendors?

Comment: 400 distinct number for MCCs and 86729 for Vendor, I gave up using  `Vendor` but the problem is MCCs look like _A hotel,B hotel, C shop, D shop..._. I want those can be clustered depending on that similarity.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to this problem using [GloVe word embeddings](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).

One way to cluster a categorical text feature is to convert each unique value into an average word vector (after removing stopwords). Then you can compare the vectors via cosine similarity, and use clustering methods based on the similarity matrix. If this approach is too computationally complex, convert the values to vectors and get top-n closest items by cosine similarity.

Comment: I tried to use the pretrained model of `GoogleNews`, lots of words were missing. As I observe, `GloVe` does not contain more words than `GoogleNews` one. Has `GloVe` a different approach for word embeddings? Thanks by the way.

Comment: The largest model from GloVe - `glove.840B.300d` has 840B tokens, 2.2M vocab, is cased, with 300 dimensional vectors. I would be surprised if many words were missing. If there are a few codes with not a single word vector, they could be assigned to an 'other' category